# How to Unlimited Limit commands FFMPEG

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg, debian-jessie

I want to ask if I have a conversion using ffmpeg on a dedicated server, 6 commands run at most. How to change this limit to more? Since 6 orders are very few. This is Debian 8.
FFMPEG version 3.0.2.

My comand ffmpeg convert is:

```
echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i " . $vstup . " -codec copy " . $vystup . " &");
```

Comment: You are running out of (time)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140258/increase-php-script-execution-time] or (memory) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830218/increase-memory-limit? Any error reports?

Comment: Your issue is in trouble. Why are you claiming the maximum instance is 6 ?

Comment: @Kewin Gozmer: he may have already setted the time limit to 0, i think more to a memory comsuption

Comment: @MTroy yes, my problem is max 6 ffmpeg convertings in same time. I need more. How to can please raise the limit? 
Current CPU usage 6% and memory usage 1700 - 2000 MB of 32 GB

Comment: ok but who is throwing the limit ? from php errors ? from ffmpeg errors ? anything is crashing over six instances ?

Comment: @MTroy no errors, all work great. My problem is: Limit 6 commands ffmpeg is same time, i need more commands..

Comment: ok, then it seem's to be auto thread managed. Try to play with "-threads x" where x is the number of threads by CPU cores , may be it will allow more instances, else , it's probably cpu related. by default its 0, but try incrementally 2, 4, 6..

Comment: @MTroy 4 core on to 8 threads have

Comment: what happens using  [xargs (click the link)](https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/2afac8aea75f4e01d7670bc2ff1afad1) ? and what is the result using the option -threads 2 in ffmpeg command ?

Comment: @MTroy how to please use xargs with my command.. 
$vstup = "something.flv";
$Vystup = "something.mp4";
echo shell_exec("ffmpeg -i " . $vstup . " -codec copy " . $vystup . " &");